# Removing steric (*) from the end of a fasta sequence in a multi fasta file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a multifasta file containi g predicted proteins from 2 abinitio tools. Every sequence contains a steric (*) in the end. I want to remove it from the file. my sequences are like this:

```
>snapgene1
SFLPSAEAIEKVLSHMSRRIIDDMKAELQQPEMRWFWP*
>snapgene2
SFLPSAEAIEKVLSHIIIIAAAAKKKPPFFDDMKAELQQPEMRWFWP*
```

i want the sequences like this :

```
>snapgen1
SFLPSAEAIEKVLSHMSRRIIDDMKAELQQPEMRWFWP
>snapgene2
SFLPSAEAIEKVLSHIIIIAAAAKKKPPFFDDMKAELQQPEMRWFWP
```

Can anyone help me in this. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If the text stored in a file "temp.txt",you can use command :

```
sed -i "s/*$//" temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk, if you keep your fastas in `file`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\*$/,"")}1' file
>snapgene1
SFLPSAEAIEKVLSHMSRRIIDDMKAELQQPEMRWFWP
>snapgene2
SFLPSAEAIEKVLSHIIIIAAAAKKKPPFFDDMKAELQQPEMRWFWP
```

It replaces trailing `*` with nothing.